# How to convert string variable from python into a javascript literal array?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have tried to convert python string data separated by commas into a javascript array variable but the process does not seem to be working.

these are my current codes:

```
    var tagstring = {{ tag_data }};
    var availableTags = new Array();
    var availableTags = tagstring.split(",");
```

I need the array to look something like this:

```
var availableTags = ["Google App Engine","jQuery"];
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

These are the working codes, thanks to the stackoverflow community :)

```
    var tagstring = "{{ tag_data }}";
    var availableTags = new Array();
    var availableTags = tagstring.split(",");
```

Basically, even though the python variable is a string, it still needs to be specified as a string variable in javascript

Comment: Please post what `{{ tag_data }}` produces, exactly.

Comment: May I suggest using a Python JSON library instead to take data from Python and put it into Javascript?

Comment: My mistake was var tagstring should be = "{{ tag_data }}";

Comment: @Gabe i have tried eval(), does not seem to work for me though. split is the best solution so far :)

Comment: Setting `availableTags` to a `new Array()` is useless here by the way, since it gets overwritten with a different array on the next line

Comment: @pivotal: Edit your question, that's much better than posting corrections in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is in a Django template, then this should work:

```
var tagstring = "{{ tag_data|escapejs }}";
```

I've added quotation marks (`"`) around the `tag_data`, since otherwise just the literal text in the string will be inserted into the Javascript; you want to construct a Javascript string that *contains* this value.

I've also used the `escapejs` tag to avoid problems with embedded backslashes, etc.

Comment: +1 for the `escapejs` filter. `escape` will not be necessary since there HTML-escaping is not needed (wrong, even) within a `<script>` tag.

Comment: by inserting |escapejs to {{ tag_data }}, would it affect my python variable that is retrieved over into the script?

Comment: @pivotal: No, the variable would remain unchanged; only the result would change

Answer (score 1):

What does

```
var tagstring = "{{ tag_data }}";
var availableTags = tagstring.split(",");
```

produce?

By the way, this can further be collapsed into a one-liner.

```
var availableTags = "{{ tag_data }}".split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is not using any string functions - be it in python or javascript - but a JSON encoder:

```
var availableTags = {{ json.dumps(elem.strip() for elem in tag_data.split(',')) }}
```

Of course it would be much nicer if you had a list in python instead of a string...